# pass object from one process to another

Tags: .net, process, ipc

I have two .NET managed assemblies. The first one is main application, and the one is an independent tool.

Now what I have to do is integrate the small tool with main application. So when user click on a button from main application the “User defined object” need to be passed to another small tool which will run into another different independent process.

But we can send only a single string argument only to a process.

What can be best approach to do this? What I need to send to another process is list of files with the settings for each file. Here setting is my “User defined object”.

I have another twist to this.

First time if you process is not running I will send parameter to it and run the process.
But if process is running, can I send parameter to it and append the data to existing one without restarting it again from scratch.

Any help regarding that. How this can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two good solutions to the above question.

1) Construct a datatable with all given input as column and write that as xml. And start a process with that file as input and read that xml file into the invoked process.
In this solution, I have no control over my new process and I can’t even debug it. I found lot of complexity while doing this.

2) So found this solution, add the exe as a reference to solution and simply invoke it with file as input as simple call to an assembly. Now have total control on it. I can even do exception handling.

Thanks everyone for reply.

Answer (score 5):

At the simplest level, you could pass a location to a file (perhaps in the temp area) containing a serialized object or some other configuration options.

More interestingly, you could pass some IPC channel information - maybe a port number to connect with a socket, etc - and establish any kind of IPC you like: remoting, WCF, raw  sockets, whatever.

Comment: Additional option would be to use standard input - if your tool is designed to read from std input then your main application can pass the serialized information by redirecting the standard input of the child process (tool)!

Comment: @VinayC well said, and simpler yet

Answer (score 4):

.NET 4 supports [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx), which is a clean, convenient and very performant mechanism for sharing arbitrary data between processes (of course you can also do this in a much more low-tech way, e.g. by writing to a temporary file).

You can create a non-persisted memory mapped file from your main process, write the serialized form of your user object to it and then deserialize it an object from within the child process. You will need to make the object class serializable (obviously) and also pass the name of the memory-mapped file from the main process to the child; however the *name* is a string so you can pass it as a command-line argument.

MSDN also has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267552.aspx) on exactly how to do this.

Comment: yea that one solution i was thinking to write all stuff required in a file from main process and pass the argument of the file to another process.

Comment: my existing solutions are not in .net 4 its in 3.0 or 3.5

Comment: @sunder: So why is the question tagged `c#-4.0`?

Comment: @sunder since the runtime version (.NET) and language version (C#) are separate and largely unrelated, there is no need to use **any** language version tag here; it won't be any different between language versions

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same problem today. At least, I solved the problem use this way:

Use Newtonsoft.Json.dll, serialize and deserialize the object, and pass string through WM_COPYDATA message.

**In host App:**

Call child app:

```
private void RunChild()
{
    string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    string childPath = Path.Combine(appPath, "ChildApp.exe");
    Process.Start(childPath, this.Handle.ToString());
}
```

Receive message:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_COPYDATA:
            COPYDATASTRUCT copyData = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
            Type type = copyData.GetType();
            copyData = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(type);
            string data = copyData.lpData;
            RestorePerson(data);
            break;
    }
}
```

Deserialize the object:

```
private void RestorePerson(string data)
{
    var p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(data);
    txtName.Text = p.Name;
    txtAge.Text = p.Age.ToString();
}
```

**In Child App:**

Get the host handle:

```
public ChildForm(string[] args)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (args.Length != 0)
        this.hostHandle = (IntPtr)int.Parse(args[0]);
}
```

Send serialized string:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.person.Name = txtName.Text;
    this.person.Age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);

    if (this.hostHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.person);
        COPYDATASTRUCT cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
        cds.dwData = (IntPtr)901;
        cds.cbData = data.Length + 1;
        cds.lpData = data;
        SendMessage(this.hostHandle, WM_COPYDATA, 0, ref cds);
    }
}

//class Person can used by HostApp by add refrence.
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

It works fine! try it?